# Oxidation of diols using periodic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

> What are the orders of rates of oxidation with $\ce{HIO4}$ of the following diols? Explain with reasons.
>
> (**a**) $\ce{Me2C(OH)C(OH)Me2}$
> (**b**) $\ce{Me2C(OH)CH(OH)Me}$
> (**c**) $\ce{CH2(OH)CH2(OH)}$
> (**d**) $\ce{MeCH(OH)CH(OH)Me}$

I know that the reaction proceeds by forming a cyclic diester of periodic acid followed by cleavage of $\ce{C-C}$ bond and formation of $\ce{C=O}$ bond.  But how do we compare the rates of the given compounds?

My first thought was to think $\ce{C-C}$ cleavage as formation of a pseudo carbocation which would be stabilised by +*I* effect of the alkyl groups and also the hyperconjugation, but I don't think it is right.

Comment: Could it possibly be related to stearic hinderance for the ring to form?

Comment: Could be but I am not sure

Comment: @SidharthGiri and Aditya One thing which you can be assured is that,whatever the differentiating factor is,it will certainly be before the formation of thr cyclic intermediate as after that,it is a pericyclic intramolecular rearrangement which is pretty easy to be done in all the cases with minimum requirement of any activation energy..

Comment: Also.. Is the answer a>b>d>c?

Comment: I don't have the answers and that is also a big problem